# node.js on shared server space

Tags: node.js, angular

I am playing with node.js and angular for first time.  I use shared server hosting space. I am trying to get some node.js tests running.

CPanel seem to provide interface to deploy node applications. Example:

```
application url: myurl.com
application root: node-hello-world
application startup file: app.js
```

This seems to create directory and some artifacts in
/home/myurl/nodevenv/node-hello-world/6/bin

I have (limited?) shell access through Cpanel emulation, however I get error on source command.

> source activate
>   got error: error: jailshell: fork: Cannot allocate memory

Does this mean node.js is installed and ready to run? Do I have to upload project as well? Where to? Trying to find more info on process of deploying to this type of server if possible.

sorry for nooby question.

Answer (score 3):

Googling your error message, I came across [this thread](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/memory-issue-running-php-scripts-from-jailshell-account.126837/) -- which admittedly is very old, but it's from cPanel and has the following comment from an administrator at the time:

> Jailshell is a constrained environment by design. It is not meant to be a replacement for a full-featured, unrestricted, shell environment, such as is provided by Bash. If your user's need such full-featured environments then perhaps they need full shell access, or another method whereby they can accomplish their goal.

That answer was given in 2006 (yes, 13 years ago) but I have to imagine the spirit of that response is still true.

To be perfectly honest, I'd be afraid to use any shared hosting provider that would give you more than **very** limited shell to use -- it opens the door to many security vulnerabilities, and if multiple customers are in the same runtime (i.e. shared hosting) it could be catastrophic. Maybe your host does allow this, or maybe what you're describing isn't actually the same thing I'm referring to... you didn't offer a lot of details on this point.

Back to your question: `Does this mean node.js is installed and ready to run? Do I have to upload project as well? Where to?`

If I had to guess, Node probably isn't installed (it isn't in most shared hosting providers) -- but I can't say for sure based on the information you provided. My recommendation would be to call their customer support. Or pay for a dedicated hosting account where you get root access. Or just use something like Heroku.